# UICollectionView doesn't create a new cell if the cell is shown using (indexPath.item % n == 0). It doesn't create new cell for multiples of a number

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using this condition to create specific UICollectionViewCells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if(indexPath.item % 3 == 0){//multiples of 3
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1id", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
        cell.backgroundColor = .white

        if(cell.wasCreated){
            cell.cellLabel.text = "Cell(1) \(indexPath.item) was created before."
        }
        else{
            cell.cellLabel.text = "Creating cell(1) \(indexPath.item) first time."
            cell.wasCreated = true
        }

        return cell
    }
    else{
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2id", for: indexPath) as! Cell2
        cell.backgroundColor = .gray

        if(cell.wasCreated){
            cell.cellLabel.text = "Cell(2) \(indexPath.item) was created before."
        }
        else{
            cell.cellLabel.text = "Creating cell(2) \(indexPath.item) first time."
            cell.wasCreated = true
        }

        return cell
    }
}//end cellForItemAt
```

Here 'wasCreated' is a variable within the cell that I'm using to check if the cell is being created for the first time, if it is I set `wasCreated = true` and this should be done, for the first time, for every cell but it isn't.
The condition is: if the `indexPath.item` is a multiple of 3, deque cell 1 otherwise cell 2.
Now normally, when a cell is to be displayed for the first time the cell's init() method is called but in this case it's not called and the older cell is being dequed for some reason.
I have no idea why this is happening.

I have uploaded a sample project that reproduces the problem. Here's the link:  https://github.com/AfnanAhmadiOSDev/IndexMultiplesTest.git

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant code.  You should note, however, that is normal for cells to be re-used.  You should not rely on the initialiser to configure your cell.  You can use `prepareForReuse` in the cell class or configure your cell in `cellForRow(at:)`

Comment: I'm no relying on the initializer. My problem that the initializer should be called whenever a cell is to be shown for the first time, but it isn't.

Comment: What do you mean "for the first time".  Do you mean the first time a given `indexPath.item` is shown?  If so, then no, that is not how it works.  Cells are re-used - Note the function name `dequeueReusableCell` - *Reusable*

Comment: the init triggers each time you dequeue

Comment: You're not getting my point.
Okay say if I have a variable called 'wasCreated' inside the cell set to 'false' by default. Now when dequeuing the cell I check if this variable is 'true', I set it to false. This scenario should work once for every cell and when a cell is re-used, the value for that cell's 'wasCreated' should be returned. But in my case it's not. Could you at least try the demo project I've attached once and then give your opinions.

Comment: I downloaded your sample and it behaves exactly as I expected

Comment: Seriously ?
Then why do cell's until 'Creating cell(2) 5 first time' have their own value for 'wasCreated' but after that the previous value is used for every next cell.(for the first scroll, I'm not talking about scrolling up & down)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is expected.  To reduce memory use, cells are reused as the collection view scrolls.

When you call `dequeueReusableCell` UIKit checks to see if there is a cell with the requested identifier that has moved offscreen and is therefore eligible for reuse.  If there is, then this cell is returned.  In this case `init` will not be called.  If there is no candidate cell then a new cell instance is returned and `init` will be called.

When you run your code you will see that cells are being created at first, but after you scroll up and down sufficiently to build up a large enough cell reuse pool cells are re-used and no new cells are created.

Cell reuse is independent of the `IndexPath` for which the cell was previously used.

Comment: Yes.  It behaves exactly as I would expect and as I have described in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand what output you are expecting to see?  Are you expecting to see continual "first time" cells as you scroll?

Comment: No. I understand the concept of re-use. The cell at index 6 should have 'wasCreated' as false by default when it scrolled to for the first time. I know it's re-used once it has been displayed. But even on first scroll it has 'wasCreated' as true.

Comment: It actually depends on the device you run it on. On an iPhone 5 you will see that cell 6 is the first cell that is reused.  On an iPhone XR cell 9 is the first one that is reused.  UIKit manages the size of the reuse pool in order to balance memory vs having sufficient cells "off screen" to ensure smooth scrolling and minimise calling `cellForItemAt`.  This behaviour isn't documented and is opaque.

Comment: Aren't cells supposed to be 're-used' once they have been used ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190603/discussion-between-paulw11-and-afnanahmad).